# Overwrite attribute table using python

Tags: python, overwrite, arcpy

When I try to use python codes to add fields and update the fields using geometry (x and y) to the attribute table of feature class, it gives me this error:

> field A already exists
>           Failed to execute (AddField).

I used

```
  arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

in my codes but seem not to work.

How to overwrite attribute table of feature class? Does this overwrite code also work for the overwriting attribute table? I know that even for geoprocessing the codes don't work well sometimes.

Comment: Note: AddField will not fail if the field definition of the existing field is the same as the one you were trying to add.

Answer (score 1):

`arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` will overwrite existing datasets, not existing fields.

You should ckeck if the field exists, and if it does, either:

Delete it and re-add it:

```
if len(arcpy.ListFields(your_dataset, A)) > 0:
  arcpy.DeleteField_management(your_dataset, A)
  arcpy.AddField_management(your_dataset, A, field_type)
```

Not add it:

```
if len(arcpy.ListFields(your_dataset, A)) > 0:
  arcpy.AddMessage("Field A already exists")
else:
  arcpy.AddField_management(your_dataset, A, field_type)
```

Comment: Yes sorry I've forgotten a closing bracket. I've updated the code.